# Side effects of TreeSet using a custom Comparator that never returns 0

Tags: java, treemap

Below is what I would consider to be a "normal" (although not efficient) `Comparator`:

```
private final class SampleComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

I am wondering what are the side effects of using a `Comparator` that will never return `0`:

```
private final class SampleComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a <= b) return -1; // Less than equals
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

These `Comparator`s are made up for SO. The real context is that someone I work with had implemented a lot of code thinking `TreeSet` allowed for duplicate items and wanted a way to force duplicate items. I realize that a solution could just be using `TreeMap` where values are `ArrayList` (each `ArrayList` would have one or more elements)

Comment: The side effects will be implementation specific.  `Comparator` explicitly says > The implementor must ensure that signum(compare(x, y)) == -signum(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

Comment: This violates the [contract of `Comparator::compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)), in particular this part: "*The implementor must ensure that `signum(compare(x, y)) == -signum(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.*"

Comment: I'm curious about what your TreeMap+ArrayList data structure is trying to accomplish. It sounds like you're trying to track disjoint groups of objects that are somehow "equal", is that right?

Comment: If so, you might wish to look at disjoint-set forests (aka union-find). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @AlexReinking, The actual stored elements are not `Integer`, they have multiple members One of those members is a timestamp and it is possible for those timestamps to be the same among different elements